# Creating a class in Angular from JSON Response Object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I would like to create a model/class for my Angular App from the following response template:

```
{
 "id": {integer},
 "name": {string},
 "make": {
       "id": {integer},
       "name": {string},
       "niceName": {string}
 },
 "model": {
   "id": {string},
   "name": {string},
   "niceName": {string}
 },
 "year": {
   "id": {integer},
   "year": {integer}
 },
 "submodel": {
   "body": {string},
   "fuel": {string}, // is not always populated
   "tuner": {string}, // is not always populated
   "modelName": {string},
   "niceName": {string}
 },
 "trim": {string},
 "states": {array},
 "engine": {object},
 "transmission": {object},
 "options": [
   {
     "category": {string},
     "options": {array}
   }
 ],
 "colors": [
   {
  "category": {string},
  "options": {array}
  }
  ],
 "drivenWheels": {string},
 "numOfDoors": {string},
 "squishVins": {array},
 "categories": {object},
 "MPG": {object},
 "manufacturerCode": {string},
 "price": {object}
 }
```

into something like this:

```
class SearchResult {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 make: {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  niceName: string;
 };
 model: {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  niceName: string;
 };
 year: {
  id: number;
  year: number;
 };
```

Some caveats:

1. Most of these fields have multiple "objects/data" for "colors" (Interior and Exterior) and Options (5 different categories) - how do I build an 'abstract' loop that can handle a variable amount of colors, and others, etc.
2. Some fields return an object - how do I handle that?
3. Take "model" for example - it's an object with 3 fields, 'make' and 'submodel' are similar. How would I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make those objects into models!

So the example you gave would look like:

```
import {Make, Model, Year} from "../my_models";

class SearchResult {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 make: Make;
 model: Model;
 year: Year;
```

For arrays of primatives or objects the syntax would be:

```
import {Color} from "../my_models";   

class SearchResult{
    ...
    colors: Color[];
    options: string[];
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes! thats exactly what I should do! now, how do I format my models?

This makes sense to me on a theoretical level, but how would my models look like? Where do I put it in the file structure (according to convention) can you elaborate your code for me to apply it to my project? Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll define the models the same way as your SearchResult class, until you have only primatives left :)

Comment: I see what you're saying, now I'm going to create a models file, but where? and does each model have to be separated in a different file (i prefer this)? How do I go about having many color objects in my main "SearchResult" ?

Comment: You can put them in separate files and export them individually, or you can "barrel" them by re-exporting all of them from one file (similar to my example above)

Comment: For the many colors, note the Color[] in my second example -- this will give you an array of color objects.

Comment: marked this answer as correct. 1. Am I supposed to expect that these models will handle the multiple nested objects ('Color[]' natively with no extra code?) 2. I want these models to be universal throughout all my components. Where in my Project is it best to place this (and naming conventions) (I am a newb who wants to do this 100% right/angular way)

Comment: It's hard to say for file structure, that will have to be up to you.  And yes, the models will work for arrays of objects that have arrays etc.  As far as the reception of data, you may need an custom mapper if the JSON doesn't conform to your schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134992/discussion-between-miguel-and-chrispy).